# Is it possible to include some kind of OR logic when using String split?

Tags: java, string, split

Say you have:

```
String example = "This is [my] example";
```

Is there a way for example.split(regex) to work on both whitespace and the square brackets simultaneously? As in: "If whitespace, [, or ] is encountered, split the string."

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) is a regular expression, so you can write:

```
example.split("[ \\[\\]]")
```